# Supersize plugin error in internet explorer 7 and 8

Tags: plugins

Supersize plug in works great in firefox and safari but won't load in ie at all and brings up the following error

line: 13
Char: 1152
'd.options.slides[…].thumb' is null or not an object

any help much appreciated

Site is http://ac-design.no

Comment: This is a user support question and would be better served in the [official support forums](http://wordpress.org/support).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you get in touch with the plugin author and make him/her aware of the problem. I did a quick search and found someone else with the same issue. Maybe this will help you:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wp-supersized-comma-in-image-list-causes-plugin-to-break-in-ie7-and-8?replies=1